# select a dropdown with a class within a parent div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to select a `select` menu that is under a parent div. I keep getting nothing returned though.

```
$('#content_container > .vendor_address_select');
```

what is incorrect here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#content_container .vendor_address_select');
```

You don't need to have the greater than sign. This will apply to all the descendants of `content_container` with the class of `vendor_address_select`

This method is using `jQuery Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)`. It is referenced here in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/).

Mad Echet has a great point that `>` means that `.vendor_adress_select` is a child of `#content_container`

Comment: thank you very much! how exactly does this selection work. do you have a link to the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

You should post the HTML but the `>` means the `.vendor_adress_select` is a direct child of `#content_container` so if it is a grand-child you will not receive anything in response.

Comment: aha! thanks. How can I make it so it checks all the decedents?

Comment: However bear in mind it has performance impact. If you use the `>` it will parse the children only, which is faster than parsing the whole descendants tree. Always prefer simple selectors. Can you afford to have a unique id `#vendor_adress_select` for your select item? `$("#vendor_adress_select")` would be way faster.

Comment: no, i can't do it by id. And anyway it's only about 6 select boxes at the most, so i don't think the performance is that hindered. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting your element more directly. You shouldn't need to use a combinator. Also, are you by chance mixing .js scripts (prototype.js with jQuery.js?) If you are mixing scripts, you may need to use jQuery's No Conflict rule.

Try this though:

```
$(".vendor_address_select")
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to find any children in the parent element:

```
$('#content_container').find('.vendor_address_select');
```

this will find children element at any level. cheout the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/xdC6T/**